# Hovering over Span moves image

Tags: javascript, css

I currently having a rounded image set in my top right corner, and I didn't have any problems until I moved it from the left to the right. If you hover over the span, it opens the nav menu but it also moves the rounded image. When not hovering it stays in the position that I please. How can I fix this?

**CSS**

```
.dropbtn {
  padding: 16px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
.show {display:block;}
.rounded-circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <span onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><img class="rounded-circle avatar-align" src="/assets/fallback/default-avatar-3-9fe9418585e4df60d6d1005ccf4f0c8ee871f01710b4d10c496f45b8a0ef9305.png">  </span>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="/users/sign_in">Log in</a>
    <a href="/users/sign_up">Sign up</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you produce a runnable snippet, or at least the HTML markup as well..

Comment: My bad, fix it and added an HTML snippet.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cfoaw390/ Try modifying this to make the problem happen, I can't find what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `.dropdown-content` css with the below one.

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  right:20px
}
```

Here what I updated is replaced `position:relative` to `position:absolute` and added `right:20px` in `.dropdown-content` class.

Check the working snippet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  const dropDown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  dropDown.classList.contains("show") ?dropDown.classList.remove("show") :dropDown.classList.add("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  padding: 16px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  z-index:99;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  right:20px
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.rounded-circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><img class="rounded-circle avatar-align" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300"> </span>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="/users/sign_in">Log in</a>
    <a href="/users/sign_up">Sign up</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed the moving of the character, but now the button is basically under the image. and not on top, so it's out of line.

Comment: @MartinIAm This is because your `window.click` event is working along with the `myFunction()`, so when `myFunction()` is called it will add `show` class to the block, at the same time `window.click()` will also trigger, this will remove the `show` class. To prevent that add ` event.stopPropagation();` to the `myFunction()`.  Check the updated snippet